# CSS not applied while adding returned CSS from a function to a styled-component for IE11?

Tags: css, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, next.js, styled-components

I have written a function which returns CSS generated over iteration on an object and I want to use the returned CSS in a styled-component

```
const getCss = (object, theme) => {
  let template = ``;
  Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
    template += `
      ${theme.breakpoints.up(key)} {
        max-height: ${object[key]}em;
      }
    `;
  });
  console.log(template);
  return template;
};
```

which returns this

```
      @media (min-width:0rem) {
        max-height: 1em;
      }

      @media (min-width:48rem) {
        max-height: 1em;
      }

      @media (min-width:80rem) {
        max-height: 1em;
      }

      @media (min-width:90rem) {
        max-height: 2em;
      }
```

and I am using the getCSS() like this -

```
const StyledContainer = styled.span`
${({ theme, sizeObject, color }) => css`
    * {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

      @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        display: -webkit-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        line-height: ${theme.typography.lineHeight};
        ${typeof lineClamp === 'object'
          ? lineClamp !== null && getCss(lineClamp, theme)
          : `${theme.breakpoints.up('xs')} {
        max-height: ${lineClamp * theme.typography.lineHeight}
       }`}
      }
      }`}
```

but the CSS doesn't get applied to it 
[image: actual generated CSS]

Comment: Do you mean `display: -webkit-box` and `-webkit-box-orient: vertical` not applied in IE? That's because IE doesn't support [-webkit-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-flex#Browser_compatibility) and [box-orient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient#Browser_compatibility). You need to use the css styles that IE supports. You could make [a minimal demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with html and css codes which showing the styles you want then we can test and see how to make it compatible in IE.

Comment: @YuZhou No, the max-height property isn't being applied

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE 11? Does `getCSS()` returned the right value when you use it in IE 11? I try to use your code to test but there're errors and I can't reproduce the issue. Could you please provide a minimal sample with css, js, html or whatever codes necessary so that we can reproduce the issue? You could use some online code editors to show the sample. We'll test it and see how to help. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Yu Zhou I have updated the sample code, thank you very much

Comment: You could check the `lineClamp` value to see if it is right because the value can affect the max-height property. Besides, I noticed that you used `forEach` in your `getCSS()` function. IE doesn't support `forEach` for HTMLCollection. You need to polyfill it in IE. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878482/mixitup-javascript-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer/60925167#60925167) for the polyfill.